# Circuit analysis of a halfwave rectifier

Tags: diodes, mesh-analysis

I want to verify whether my calculations are correct. Additionally, there are two questions related to this circuit: 'What is the purpose of R1 and R2 in the given circuit?' and 'What is the intended application of this circuit?' I am unable to think of any specific reasons or applications for this circuit type, can you please enlighten me. Thank you.

circuit
[image]

waveform

[image: Waveform]

question

[image: Question]

answer
[image: Circuit]

Comment: Just eyeballing it I get one peak of 16 V and another peak of 26.667 V. But I only spent less than 60 seconds on it. I probably missed something. What's the answer supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my simple analysis:
When Vin is positive: D2 conducts. R2 (1k1) is connected directly across Vin, and plays no part in setting Vout (assuming Vin has zero internal impedance).  So, Vout is determined by the resistive divider formed by RL(2k2) and R1(3k3).
So Vout peak = 0.40 x 40V = +16.00V ==> 11.31V RMS (divide by sqrt 2 to get RMS).
On the scope, Vout will appear as a positive half-sine with a peak = 16.0V.

When Vin is negative: D1 conducts. R1 (3k3) is connected directly across Vin, and plays no part in setting Vout.  Vout is determined by the resistive divider formed by RL(2k2) and R2(1k1).
So Vout peak = 0.667 x 40V = +26.67V ==> 18.86V RMS.
On the scope, Vout will appear as a positive half-sine with a peak = 26.67V.

Assuming the frequency of Vin is much faster than the display update rate of the meter, and assuming the meter reads true RMS at the frequency of Vin, the meter reading will be the average of these two values, so:
Meter reading = 0.5 x (11.31V +  18.86V) = +15.09V.

As for practical application: I am stumped by the frequency of 0.7958Hz.  Never seen this frequency used in real life, I guess it is just set by the angular frequency of sin(5t), 5 rads/sec ==> 0.7958Hz.  At such a low frequency, the assumption that the meter will display the average value may no longer hold, so in reality you may see the meter display alternating between 11.31V & 18.86V - and that is assuming the meter is still reading true RMS at this very low frequency.

As for the purpose of R1 & R2: These set the other half of the resistive divider formed with the load resistor, depending on the polarity of the input voltage.  Vout is higher for negative Vin than for positive Vin.  I am not really sure if this circuit with these resistor values has a practical, real-world application.